# Send HTML-formatted email messages from Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Is there any way to send a mail in HTML format (and if possible with attachments) when your default mail client isn't Outlook?

Many thanks for any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use CDO (Collaboration Data Objects). The code will look something like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub cdoHtmlTest()
    Const urlPrefix = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
    Dim msg As Object  ' CDO.Message
    Set msg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")  ' New CDO.Message
    With msg.Configuration.Fields
        .Item(urlPrefix & "sendusing") = 2  ' cdoSendUsingPort
        .Item(urlPrefix & "smtpserver") = "smtp.example.com"
        .Item(urlPrefix & "smtpserverport") = 25
        .Item(urlPrefix & "smtpauthenticate") = 1  ' cdoBasic
        .Item(urlPrefix & "sendusername") = "mySmtpUserName"
        .Item(urlPrefix & "sendpassword") = "mySmtpPassword"
        .Item(urlPrefix & "smtpusessl") = False
        .Update  ' remember to do this step!
    End With
    With msg
        .To = "gord@example.com"
        .From = "gord@example.com"
        .Subject = "HTML message test"
        .HTMLBody = "This is a <strong>TEST</strong>."
        .Send
    End With
    Set msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

For more examples (including how to send attachments), look [here](http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm).

Comment: Happy New year and thanks for your assist. I was away during the vacation and I'm back now. The above example is exactly what I was looking for but let me ask you two more questions. 1- Is it possible to show(view-edit) the mail before sending it. 2-Is there any way to hide the smpt password? Million thanks for any further help

Comment: I found this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526365%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx . It seems the only methods for **Message** object is **Send** & **Delete**

Comment: @Tera **(1)** To preview the message I suppose that you could either dump the `.HTMLBody` text to a rich-text Text Box control on a form, or dump it to an HTML file and open it in a browser. **(2)** There are ways that you could obfuscate the SMTP password, but to completely hide it you'd probably have to [hide the VBA code](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/hide-vba-code-from-users-HA010239557.aspx) completely.